# Remove the apply button from a Facebook job I posted

Tags: facebook

Can I and if so how do I remove the apply button from a Facebook job I posted?  I do not see an option to add or remove the apply button when I create a job on my Facebook page.

Answer (score -1):

You right click on the three dots just by the side of it.